# Methodology to fix 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Breakdown' for a Django Project

Tags: python, django

I have a workout progress project that I am working on and I am trying to find the breakdown of each exercise which is reps and order. Here is the model for clarification:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30,blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("my_gym:workout", kwargs={'workout_id': self.id})

class Exercise(models.Model):
    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='exercises',blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Breakdown(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='breakdown',blank=True, null=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],blank=True, null=True)
    repetitions = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exercise.name + ' set #' + str(self.order)
```

I am trying to show a table after going to one of the excercises list to review the reps and order

Here is the url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('workout/<int:workout_id>/', views.workout_details, name='workout'),
]
```

Here is the views:

```
def workout_details(request,workout_id):
    template_name = 'my_gym/start_workout.html'
    # workouts = Workout.objects.filter(workout_id=workout_id)
    # excercises = Exercise.objects.get(pk=workout_id)
    excercises = Exercise.objects.filter(workout_id=workout_id)
    breakdowns=excercises.Breakdown.repetitions.all()
    context = {
        'excercises': excercises,
        'breakdowns':breakdowns
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

In the template:

```
{% for breakdowns in breakdown %}
{{excercises.breakdown.order}}
{{set.repetitions}}
    {% endfor %}
```

My question:

I am getting

`'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Breakdown'` error

I tried many options which I have commented the outcome was either getting a list of all the breakdowns of all exercises or getting nothing at all.

My object is getting for example the list of Repitions in the workout_id=1 url

Comment: In fact, each exercise has a set of breakdown objects which is accessible using the reverse related_name `sets`

Comment: In addition, `filter` returns an iterable, so you have to iterate the resulted QuerySet in order to access the breakdowns of each exercise

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down:

`excercises` is a queryset of Exercise objects

Breakdown is model that has a ForeignKey relationship to Exercise, with a related name of `sets`

So, to get the breakdowns associated with the Excercises in excercises, you can use

```
breakdowns = excercises.sets.all().order_by('order')
```

Now, in your template you can use

```
{% for exercise in excercises %}
    {{ exercise }}
    {% for breakdown in breakdowns %}
        {% if breakdown.exercise == exercise %}}
            repetitions: {{breakdown.repetitions}}<br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: to add some, with `excercises = Exercise.objects.filter(workout_id=workout_id)` Already being a queryset, you need to for wrap it with `for` so the `.set` is performed on each exercise object instead of `excercises` which is a queryset